# zlib.output_compression breaks PDF downloads in Magento

Tags: .htaccess, zlib

When i turn on zlib.output_compression, pdf generation in Magento is failing. How can i turn zlib.output_compression off within .htaccess for PDF files only ?

In PHP I could implement this.

```
if(ini_get('zlib.output_compression')) { 
    ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'Off'); 
}
```

Can I do something similar in .htaccess for PDF files only ?